# Flex 4,image create snapshoot from video display?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flex4

my code works on localhost,but not on the server,what could be the problem?I also want to return some string back from php to flex app but I can't solve that.
Here is my code :

```
        [Bindable]
        public var encodedString:String;
        [Bindable]
        public var img_name:String;
        [Bindable]
        public var pid:int;         
        [Bindable]
        public var url_string:String;                   

        protected function btn_save_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width,videoDisplay.height-25);             
            bmpData.draw(videoDisplay);

            var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);  
            img.source = bm;  

            var jpg_e:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            bytes = jpg_e.encode(bmpData);

            var b64e:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder()
            b64e.encodeBytes(bytes);

            encodedString = b64e.flush();

        }


        protected function btn_save_image_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            save_img.send();
        }
```

```
        <mx:request xmlns="">
            <img_data>                  
                {encodedString}
            </img_data>
            <image_name>
                {img_name}
            </image_name>
            <post_id>
                {pid}
            </post_id>
        </mx:request>

    </mx:HTTPService>
```

When click save,I want to save snapshoot from videodisplay to img.Also I send image to php,and want to get simple text answer that is done,but I always get object returned.

and I save image with php,and just print message,like this :

> print "this is message!";

I think the problem is when I need to save image from control(video display) to image control,but this problem only occure on server but not on localhost

Comment: By the way, you should accept answers / upvote answers that are useful (esp. on your other questions.) or people will start to ignore your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the last line from:

```
str = b64e;
```

To:

```
str = b64e.toString();
```

Note that calling `toString()` will clear the `b64e` object.

### Update:

Let's try placing the video in a container, and then doing the `.draw()` on that, we'll add some additional content to it so that we can get that if the video doesn't show up.

```
<s:Group id="videoContainer">
  <mx:Label text="Hello" />
  <mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" />
</s:Group>
```

Hopefully you are already doing the VideoDisplay part of this, and you can update your code to add the containing group.

When you do the `.draw()` use `videoContainer` instead of `videoDisplay` ie. :

```
 bmpData.draw(videoContainer);
```

This is just to test, if there is a sandbox issue, which it defintely seems to be, only "Hello" will show up in the bitmap, and the video will still not be seen.

Comment: But then I pass string to my php script,if I accept that string in my php as string and try to save it as image,will that work ? I'm not sure.

Comment: Base64 is just a string, a handler will encode/decode as binary.

Comment: you are right,I update my post,but still I can't return anything from php

Comment: Run this through the debugger and set a breakpoint on `str = b64e.toString();` and see if there's anything in `b64e` and `bytes`.

Comment: Hi,I didn't debug,because it is hard for me to do that,it is connected  with wp,so it is hard for me to do that.I realize that problem maybe is on when I try to save image from video disply to img control.

Comment: I return now json object from php script and parse it in flex,only issue that I have left is image to save from video display to image component on server,not sure what is the problem because on localhost this works.

Comment: Well, given the information we have, it sounds like it may be a sandbox issue, as suggested by *Florian F*.  However, I find it difficult to determine what exactly is going on. What do you mean by "connected with wp"?  But even so, if you get good results localhost, and fails on the remote server. We need to clarify what is the URL of the swf and  what is the URL of the video that you are viewing? If these two even use different subdomains, we need to ensure the crossdomain  policy is inplace on the video's domain.

Comment: connected to wordpress - sorry,it is wordpress website,yes it works fine on localhost,no it use same domain,I dont have subdomain.url of swf is http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/test.flv and page url is http://example.com/test-page/?post_id=201 Tnx Slomojo for your time.

Comment: As a test, create the bitmap using a different source object, something that doesn't rely on an external asset. For example a text item, that way you can breakdown the problem into smaller pieces. Then we should be able to identify what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Yes,it works I can save now image from other source object.So problem is file(video) that is loaded dynamically.How to fix this? tnx Slomojo again

Comment: Ok, let's try this. Put the video in a Sprite, overlay a text item (also contained in the Sprite) and do the .draw() on the Sprite. Let's see what we get.

Comment: what to do ? I'm not flex developer,it will take me time to try that - to find out what that mean,can you help me also with that,sorry :)

Comment: If you provide the real URL instead of example.com I could verify, otherwise we're in the dark here and can't really move beyond the obvious problem of sandboxing.

Comment: Ok, to add the sprite follow the code in my answer (I'm updating it now, so it'll appear in a few moments.)

Comment: no,I don't see hello,it is not working,I don't know is this important to you,I only change <s:Label x="10" y="10" text="Hello" /> because when I use mx it show me an error.is that important if I use s: or mx: I know that s is for spark,...

Comment: yes, you can use spark instead, now do the same again, but comment out the VideoDisplay. - if it now works, it's the sandbox, and if you insist it's on the same domain, I'm afraid we've reached a dead end.

Comment: let me check that,I hope that it is not dead end :(((

Comment: if you can provide the real URL of the video file and the deployed SWf, I can quickly determine if they should have sandbox issues or not. (instead of example.com, which I can't verify of course.)

Comment: Yes,if I comment videoDisplay,I can see hello

Comment: how to fix sandbox problem ? I'm looking on the web,for example,can you help me with that?

Comment: it is hard to do that,because it is part of wordpress backend,and I will need to give login data,and that is not good for me :((

Comment: do you have skype or fb or msn ? :)))

Comment: why is there cross domain issue if file and page are on the same server ?

Comment: I receive video display source value from server in my flex app with flashvars,is that important ?

Comment: I put this crossdomain.xml file in root folder whit this content,but this didn't help  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">  
<cross-domain-policy>  
    <allow-access-from domain="*.example.com" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: what is the video source value? providing the SWF URL and Video URL will not compromise your wordpress security.

Comment: Here is flv video url http://muskimagazin.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/plava-riba_flv.flv , but page for creating snapshots is in backend

Comment: ok,here is temp page that I create http://www.muskimagazin.com/man-snapshoot/?post_id=19029 same issue as in backend

Comment: ok, `musicmagazin.com` and `www.musicmagazin.com` are not the same domain (even though they probably alias to the same domain) - make sure the reference to the flv uses `www.musicmagazin.com` and try again. Hopefully you understand that a subdomain `www` is not the same as it's parent domain. Flash doesn't bother doing any sort of DNS lookups to see if they resolve to the same address, it just sees that the domain name is not equal.

Comment: because `"musicmagazin.com" != "www.musicmagazin.com"` ... and that's all the flash player will do when checking domains... When people start talking abount Flash crossdomain / sandboxing... Pay very close attention to your urls. Aliased domains are not equal.

Comment: It trips up EVERY person that develops Flash/Flex stuff... so don't worry about it, basically though, if you have the code syntax right, and you can't manipulate an asset somehow, it's 99%+ positive that it's crossdomain/sandbox.

Comment: I intend to start learing flex,because it is great,tnx for tips and for the help

Comment: Flex 4 is definitely a nice way to develop Rich Internet Apps (RIAs) - but personally I find the interop / accessibility limitations a bit too restrictive.

Comment: BTW, note that if you'd used relative URLs for all these assets you wouldn't have had the problem.

Comment: hmm,that is great,will try that,I can't remember when I last time use relative urls in php,...

Comment: they are useful because you can move your app around on different domains without any issues.

Comment: yes,is there any other tricky thing in flex that maybe cause me problems in the future ? :))))))

Comment: Thankfully a lot of old issues with Flash are not so bad anymore, but you just need to get on with it and develop your solutions and if something goes wrong, seek answers.

Comment: yes,this was annoying,I knew that is some stupid issue,it is always some stupid issue. :) tnx mate,byeeeeee

Comment: A big +1 for the considerable effort

Answer (score 2):

Where does that video come from? Camera? FMS?

It might be either a crossdomain issue or something related to FMS (or another streaming server).

This post could help you : [How do I specify a crossdomain policy file to allow Flash to grab a bitmap from an RTMP (Wowza) video stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215127/how-do-i-specify-a-crossdomain-policy-file-to-allow-flash-to-grab-a-bitmap-from-a)

Comment: I load video(url) from database to video display when page is loaded,I'm not flex dev,I'm just trying to connect with php

Comment: The important issue is the relative locations of the hosts, if you are getting content from a host that is different (DNS wise) to the host that is serving the Flash content, you will run into issues with the Flash crossdomain security policy.

Comment: hmm,not sure what you mean,www.example.com is my host,and www.example.com/post_id=234 is page from where I'm pulling content,I can play that video that is loaded dinamicly in video player,but I can't create snapshoot from that video,that is very strange?HOW to fix that ?

Comment: @User303832 - dinamicly ... dynamically. ;)