# How to capture a streaming video display and save it to disk in Flex Builder 3?

Tags: flex3, flexbuilder, screenshot, videodisplay

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a while and didn't get the answer.
I have a page with a **VideoDisplay** object and a "Take screenshot" button. I would like to get the screenshot from the streaming video and save it but I'm getting an error:

> Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: http://xxx/xxx.swf cannot access rtmp://xxx/xx/xx/. No policy files granted access.

The domain of the website from which I'm capturing the image and the rtmp is the same.

I'm using **ImageSnapshot** class to capture the screenshot. This is the function responsible for taking the screenshot:

```
function takeSnapshot()
    {
        var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot=ImageSnapshot.captureImage(mainPlayer);
        var imageByteArray:ByteArray=imageSnap.data as ByteArray;
        var fileRef:FileReference=new FileReference();
        fileRef.save(imageByteArray, "screenshot.png");
    }
```

I've got also a cross-domain policy file with a lin:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
```

I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems someone has figured it out.
He was having an issue with not connecting to the stream correctly
[Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215127/how-do-i-specify-a-crossdomain-policy-file-to-allow-flash-to-grab-a-bitmap-from-a)

Answer (score 0):

> Flash Player cannot access bitmap data
>   or sound spectrum data for media
>   loaded from RTMP sources, although it
>   can display and play bitmaps and
>   sounds loaded from these servers.

Comment: Can you add a link to where you found this statement?

Comment: It seems someone was able to get a snap shot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215127/how-do-i-specify-a-crossdomain-policy-file-to-allow-flash-to-grab-a-bitmap-from-a

Comment: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flashplayer/pdfs/flash_player_10_security.pdf

page 50

Comment: Interesting page 49 just as you quoted. I wonder how that guy got it working on the link I posted.