# ActionScript 2: Can't grab video frame to a bitmap

Tags: flash, bitmap, actionscript-2

I am trying to grab a video frame from RTMP video. the video is played very well and i can see it on my video surface, but i can't grab it to a bitmap and the bitmap is black.. :(
I need to do it with **ActionScript 2**.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.*;

var i = 0;
var kVIDEOW = 720;
var kVIDEOH = 576;
var vidBmpHolder:BitmapData;
var vidBmpDisplay:BitmapData;
var vidBmp = createEmptyMovieClip("bmp", 0);
var vidBmpRect:Rectangle;
var vidBmpPoint:Point;

var connection_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
connection_nc.connect("rtmp://tvserver.chaneladd.tv:1935/live");
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection_nc);


vidBmpHolder = new BitmapData(kVIDEOW, kVIDEOH, false, 0x000000);
vidBmpDisplay = new BitmapData(kVIDEOW, kVIDEOH, false, 0x000000);
vidBmpRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, kVIDEOW, kVIDEOH);
vidBmpPoint = new Point(0, 0);
// Create the Bitmap display object
vidBmp.attachBitmap(vidBmpDisplay,0);
vidBmp.x = 0;
vidBmp.y = 0;

if (stream) 
{
    video.my_video.attachVideo(stream);
    stream.play("437.stream");

    onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
        video.my_video.attachVideo(null);
        vidBmpHolder.draw(video);
        video.my_video.attachVideo(stream);
        vidBmp.attachBitmap(vidBmpHolder,0);
        addChild(vidBmp);
    };
}
else
{
    trace("not connected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [How to capture a streaming video display and save it to disk in Flex Builder 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017259/how-to-capture-a-streaming-video-display-and-save-it-to-disk-in-flex-builder-3)

In short, it can't be done because it violates a security restriction. A document explaining it is on page 49 here: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flashplayer/pdfs/flash_player_10_security.pdf